# Flutter cannot delete build folder when flutter clean is executed

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Whenever I try to clean my flutter project by using the command 
`flutter clean` I get an error saying

```
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used
```

I can understand that there is some directory opened and it has to closes in order to clean. But I cannot understand which one is it. I tried **restarting my computer** to resolve this issue. But still when I run the command **flutter clean** I get the error.

Comment: in your flutter project, try `rm -rf build` otherwise `flutter build clean`?

Comment: both these commands doesnt work, im using windows. Also, when i press ```flutter build clean``` i get ```Could not find a subcommand named "clean" for "flutter build".```

Answer (score 30):

If you moved your project folder to another place then just `**delete** your "build" folder` and

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

you will be fine:)
Cheers.

Comment: is there an explanation as to why flutter can not delete the build folder in this scenario ?

Answer (score 9):

Simply run your cmd as administrator then run the command. As simple as that.

Thank me later.. :)

Comment: It's not as simple as that, that will not solve this.

Comment: Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Android Studio then just go to

File->Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 5):

The answer is found in the link u were sent to go to which was 
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used

Apparently, you need to download Microsoft's Process Explorer  to help you figure out which program is that.

It will let you know which app is handling that folder and you will also be able to kill that handle.

Find -> Find handle -> search for folder's name (will take a while..)

Comment: What folder name do you need to search?

Comment: You navigate to the folder you are try to delete. When you have it open you search for the exact name of the folder, eg. FolderName2 or ThisIsMyProjectFolder.

Answer (score 3):

Try to delete build folder manually.  If it shows  `using a file in the directory error` then identify the process and kill or simply restart machine.

Then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Additionally try invalidate cache in IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Shut down any instances of openJDK or java in task manager, than run it within a cmd window with admin privileges.

Answer (score 2):

If it all fails, just restart the computer and you can start from where you left.

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Task Manager
2. search for any Flutter Application running in the Background process, click and End Task
3. Run flutter clean in IDE

The Reason was Flutter Clean cant delete the build while the Application is still running in the Background process, u have to close it and run.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close your IDE.
2. Open cmd as administrator by right clicking on Start icon.
3. Change the directory from `C:\Windows\system32>` to your flutter
   directory.
4. Then run `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above solutions and the following order worked for me.

1. Open Task Manager and end any java(JDK) related processes.
2. Android studio File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
3. Once restart the IDE pub get

Answer (score 0):

kill OpenJDK instance from task manager

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue before;

Quit vscode or android studio (whichever you're using) and follow the below steps

1. Open the command line (CMD) as administrator
2. Go to the root directory of the project.
3. run `flutter clean` command

Answer (score 0):

flutter lib folder and all dart file major red lines in vscode
so  use this two commands
flutter clean
and
flutter pub get
it's work
but if your error android folder then you use other way to solve the  problem

Answer (score 0):

1. end all the dart processes
2. delete build folder
   if not working then also delete .dart-tools,
   if still not then delete macos\Flutter\ephemera  folder

I had to delete all three folder to get out of this

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

1. Restart your PC (some current services block flutter clean)
2. After restart delete your build folder manually (remove write protection before)
3. Terminal in VSCode execute this command: flutter clean
4. Execute this command: flutter pub get
5. Start your App like always :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
before cleaning, just stop the running project, then clean

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After following the above steps, like closing instances and clean steps,  if you still can not delete, May be check **is there android studio or emulator or flutter app running...?**

Answer (score -1):

I tried every answer from here and then I found out it was my Avast antivirus.

Avast Antivirus (others too maybe) is notorious to block such development activity. You've to add all the SDK and project containing folders in exceptions then it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

What worked for me was **stop** anti virus program running on my PC

Then flutter clean worked fine.

After that I restated anti virus program.