# Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory

Tags: flutter, build

Whenever I try to clean my flutter project by using the command flutter clean I get an error saying

```
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used
```

My app was working fine and then suddenly this happened, tried running cmd as admin and then cleaning but it didn't work, also restarted the cache from the android studio it didn't work either.

**SOLUTION FOR ME**

I solved the problem by
Shutting down any instances of openJDK or java in task manager, than run it within a cmd window with admin privileges.

Comment: Some program is still using this folder. Maybe the emulator? IDE? File explorer?

Comment: closed all of them still same error, restarted the computer, still same error

Comment: Same error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510691/flutter-cannot-delete-build-folder-when-flutter-clean-is-executed Try the different answers

Comment: i opened this issue because none of them worked for me, but thanks

Comment: Thats weird, have you tried cmd as admin, navigate to your folder and then flutter clean or flutter build clean?

Comment: yes as i mentioned in question.

Comment: You can also delete the Build folder and try to run flutter clean

Comment: really sick of these flutter errors...

Comment: okay i solved it by deleting OpenJDK instances

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize, here is a simplified step whenever you've encountered the same issue again:

1. Open Task Manager and end any java(JDK) related processes.
2. On Android studio navigate to ***File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart***
3. Run `flutter clean` in IDE