# Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build\flutter_assets"

Tags: flutter

I've never had this error. The error doesn't appear when I run "flutter run -d chrome" for the initial flutter example but when I add a couple of folders this error appears. thank you for the help

```
Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build\flutter_assets". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.     
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The `build` folder is auto-generated when flutter runs. If you created the flutter_assets folder in the build folder, move it to the `assets` folder instead.</s> (I mixed up the assets and flutter_assets folders in my head.)

---

I had this issue and wound up manually deleting the entire build folder and running `flutter clean` (see other suggestions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510691/flutter-cannot-delete-build-folder-when-flutter-clean-is-executed) and [here on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36763)).

Comment: It only works once. Next time I run it, I get the same error.

Comment: @brikas have you run `flutter clean`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes I did, at the very least. I been sitting on this a bit more and the cause of the problem has smth to do with synced Google Drive directory, as the error dissapears when ran in a different directory. But such workaround is bad for me, since Google Drive sync is essential for me on Flutter projects.
If you could spare some time to insvestigate, I described whats happeneing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864416/flutter-run-and-clean-error-flutter-failed-to-delete-a-directory-when-project

Comment: Your solution is probably good for most cases, it just turns out that my case has extra complexity.