# Flutter run and clean error "Flutter failed to delete a directory" when project is in synced folder

Tags: flutter

Full error:
`Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build\flutter_assets". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.`

Error occurs when trying to run `flutter run -d chrome` with these notes (all on new freshly created projects):

- If the project is located in C: drive - it works always
- If the project is located in D: drive inside a synced D:\Google Drive\ folder, then it throws the error on 2nd run.
- If the project is located in D: outside of the synced folder - it works always

However, I need it to run inside the synced folder, since I am using multiple locations and computer for development of a project.

Flutter 3.3.2 • channel stable. Only using for Chrome device (web dev). I am using Windows 10. Flutter installed on D:\src\flutter.

List of things I have tried:

- Moving build folder contents to the assets folder instead. Result: runs once, but any additional runs throw the error again. As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69993997/flutter-failed-to-delete-a-directory-at-build-flutter-assets).
- `flutter clean` Result: throws same error
- Running `flutter clean` with cmd as an administrator. Result: same error
- Deleting the folder manually. Result: complains about another folder with the same error. Once I manually delete all of the ones it complains about, it runs once, but any additional runs throw the error again.
- Restarting computer
- Even tried giving `Everyone` `full-access` permissions to the project folder.
- Tried installing flutter in different location C:\src\flutter

I been trying to solve this for days and none of the answers I found on the internet work.

Flutter doctor output: https://pastebin.com/9XpHW7T8

EDIT: Tried a few more things and added them to the list.
EDIT2: Added another thing I tried.
EDIT3: Added flutter doctor output.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with iCloud as well: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36326

Comment: what is the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: @Bellrampion Ran the doctor. Here is the output: https://pastebin.com/9XpHW7T8

Comment: I can't access that on my current network. Can you post the raw output?

Comment: @Bellrampion It is above the comment char limit. Try this then: https://controlc.com/43c3db00

Comment: Suggestion from the github link: 
1. Quit Android Studio/VS Code
2. On your cli - flutter upgrade
3. Then open your project then run flutter run it should work.