# Flutter can't delete build folder with flutter clean command

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, dart-null-safety

build file doesn't remove anyway. I tried do that [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59510691/11287483) but no one work for me

how can I delete this folder?

```
    Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
    - F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-hdpi-v4
    - F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-mdpi-v4
    - F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-v21
    - F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4
    - F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\layout
```

```
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself.
```

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used

Comment: Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-hdpi-v4
F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-mdpi-v4
F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-v21
F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\drawable-xhdpi-v4
  F:\sayed\hadayek_hof\build\flutter_launch\intermediates\merged_res\release\layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your **CMD** as an *administrator* and run the command.

Then, if you are using `Android Studio` as an **IDE**, you can process this:

```
File->Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

If none of them works, just restart your computer.

Comment: Your answer is attached to answers I mentioned in the question post

It doesn't work for me

Comment: Restarting your computer didnt work?

Comment: Yes, didn't work

Comment: According to theory, the flutter clean operation failed because a program is holding a file open in one of the directories that the tool is trying to remove, Morover, I suspect there's not much the tool can do.

Comment: Temporarily, I solved this problem by pull the project from GitHub and working on it and leaving the other one unresolved

Comment: Happy for u! But this is a very specific problem related to your machine or another thing, and that's why no solution didn't work for your problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, maybe it happened in this morning after testing my Laptop Ram  