# Changes to latest version kotlin but still. Error : Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I have changed the kotlin version to latest. But when running the flutter build apk command, there is .Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.

build.gradle source:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

error:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74015909/22343394)?